# How to use more than 1 Script in FPDF

Tags: fpdf

I'm using FPDF to render a document. I've downloaded 2 scripts from the website: "Force justification" and "EPS / AI support".

The problem is that when I use FPDF with the script "Forced Justification" everything works fine but when I add "EPS / AI support" I always get this message:

**Fatal error: Cannot declare class FPDF, because the name is already in use in ...**

Is it maybe because force_justify.php and fpdf_eps.php are not made to work together or there's a solution? These are the links:

[FORCED JUSTIFICATION](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script8.php)

[EPS / AI support](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script84.php)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards

----------------EDITED----------------------

I have **adddata.php** where I have this:

```
require('force_justify.php');
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Then I have the 1st script **force_justify.php** with:

```
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
```

And the 2nd script **fpdf_eps.php** with:

```
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_EPS extends FPDF{
```

I try to follow the steps in the FAQ but I'm not sure how to do the last one:

and make your own class extend B:

```
require('b.php');

class PDF extends B
{
...
}

$pdf = new PDF();
```

Comment: Did you read the [FAQ #13](http://fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q13)?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't. I've tried but it doen't work, maybe is because I'm not sure if I've understood the last part:                                                                                             
and make your own class extend B:
require('b.php');

class PDF extends B
{
...
}

$pdf = new PDF();

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried after reading that FAQ.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. I've already have

Answer (score 1):

------------------SOLUTION-------------------

I know it was easy but sometimes first times using specific tools are hard LOL. I found the solution:

I have **adddata.php** where I create the PDF, I called fpdf_eps.php(rather than force_justify.php)

```
require 'fpdf_eps.php';
$pdf = new PDF(); //(this was my mistake because I had to use the 2nd class which extends the 1st class which extends FPDF)
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Then I have the 1st script **force_justify.php** with:

```
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
```

And the 2nd script **fpdf_eps.php** with require('force_justify.php'); (instead of fpdf.php)

```
require('force_justify.php');

class PDF_EPS extends PDF{
```

So fpdf_eps extends PDF (force_justify.php CLASS) which extends FPDF ...so I only had to use **$pdf = new PDF_EPS();** in **adddata.php** to link those 2 scripts to the main one